# Using Custom Metric for Score Method in XGBoost

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am using xgboost for a classification problem with an imbalanced dataset.  I plan on using some combination of an f1-score or roc-auc as my primary criteria for judging the model.

Currently the default value returned from the `score` method is accuracy, but I would really like to have a specific evaluation metric returned instead.  My big motivation for doing this is that I presume the `feature_importances_` attribute from the model is determined from what's affecting the `score` method, and the columns that impact predictive accuracy might very well be different from the columns that impact roc-auc.  Right now I am passing in values to `eval_metric` but it does not seem to be making a difference.

Here is some sample code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

data = load_breast_cancer()
X = data['data']
y = data['target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=0.2, stratify=y)

mod.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now at this point, `mod.score(X_test, y_test)` will return a value of ~ 0.96, and the `roc_auc_score` is ~ 0.99.

I was hoping the following snippet:

```
mod.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric='auc')
```

Would then allow `mod.score(X_test, y_test)` to return the `roc_auc_score` value, but it is still returning predictive accuracy, not `roc_auc`.

The purpose of this exercise is estimating the influence of different columns on the outcome, so if I could get `feature_importances_` returned using f1 or roc_auc as the measure of impact this would be a huge boon, but I do not seem to be on the right path as of now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question, to use `eval_metric`, you need to provide data to evaluate using `eval_set =` :

```
mod = XGBClassifier()
mod.fit(X_train, y_train,eval_set=[(X_test,y_test)],eval_metric="auc")
```

You can check the auc using evals_result(), and it gives the auc for every iteration:

```
mod.evals_result()

{'validation_0': OrderedDict([('auc',
               [0.965939,
                0.9833,
                0.984788,
                [...]
                0.991402,
                0.991071,
                0.991402,
                0.991733])])}
```

The importance score is calculated based on the average gain across all splits the feature is used in [see help page](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html?highlight=get_score#xgboost.XGBClassifier). From your question, I suppose you need the mdoel to maximize auc, like in cross-validation, but you cannot use the auc as an objective in xgboost. Gradient boosting methods require a differentiable loss function.

With imbalanced dataset, you can try to adjust the parameter `scale_pos_weight`, to adjust the balance of positive and negative weights. This is discussed in [xgboost website](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/param_tuning.html)